# How we find particular key value using populate method in node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two Schema with values in MONGODB. One is level schema and second is child schema. I am doing reference to level schema for particular key value. I storing levels 1 id to child schema DB using mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID{ref: level}. I am properly stored level 
1 id in child schema using referencing. But when I populate the level 1 id querying to my child schema it shows my level 1 id null

1). This is my schema

```
usercurrLevelId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Level',
        index: true
    }
```

2). This is second schema

```
    var LevelSchema = new Schema({

            _id: { type: String },
            age: { type: Number },
            level_num: { type: Number },
            min_score: { type: Number },
            max_questions: { type: Number }

         });

        var Level = mongoose.model('Level', LevelSchema);
```

3). This is node js code

```
  function(){
            var query = {'_id':firstinfo._id};
            var select = 'usercurrLevelId';
            childQuizInfo.find(query,select).populate({
              path: 'usercurrLevelId',
              model: 'Level',
              select: 'level_num'
            }).exec(function(err,levelno){
              if (err) return next(err);
              res.send(levelno);
              console.log(levelno);
            });
          }
```

4). The stored value in MONGODB

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57cb01e10797d129136f7997"),
"usercurrLevelId" : ObjectId("57c14943b78cd543fc59b7ee")
```

5). The output I got in console

```
[ { _id: 57cb01e10797d129136f7997, usercurrLevelId: null } ]
```